# mongo db nested object and array filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{  
 "_id": {    
    "$oid": "1234567"  
 },  
 "para": {       
   "lisobj": {      
       "abcd": 
        [  "1234"      ]    
   },
 }
}
```

I have the above mongo doc, I am trying to write a filter to see if there are any doc which have the following key:

"para.lisobj.abcd" exists.

But I am not sure what would be the proper mongo filter to find the doc which has the field.

I tried the below filter but it doesn't work:

```
{"para.lisobj.abcd" : { "exists": true} }
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss `$` at `exists`

```
db.collection.find({
  "para.lisobj.abcd": {
    $exists: true
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E8Z2ZMwjK-1)